# Bash script to check two ip addresses

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ping

I'm having a problem with a bash script i'm doing to check two ip addresses.

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c4 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null
if [ $? != 1 ]
then
echo "Device1 is up"
else
echo "Device1 is down
```

works fine however I would like it to check a second address then perform a command based on the result ie

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c4 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null
if [ $? != 1 ]
then
echo "Device1 is up"
else
ping -c4 2.2.2.2 > /dev/null
if [ $? != 1 ]
then
echo "Device2 is up"
else 
echo "Device 2 is down"
fi
```

but it doesn't work i get

```
line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Please take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Indent your code and see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a final "fi" to close off the first if...

When you nest "if" statement (one inside the other) you have to have a closing "fi" for *each* if.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something silly, many thanks

Comment: If that answers the question, please mark it as the accepted answer.